# Sequelize: Using truncate and insert within same transaction

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I need to truncate one of my table and then following it, I need to re populate it using a new dataCollection through bulkCreate. And all this should be within one single transaction I expected this to work simply but I couldn't get this to work, any suggestions how can I use `truncate` and then `bulkCreate` on a model in a single transaction?

Here's a snippet of my code

```
try {
                promises.push(
                    models.sequelize.transaction(function (t) {
                        return infx.destroy({
                            where: {},
                            truncate: true,
                            transaction: t
                        }).then(function () {
                            return infx.bulkCreate(dataCollection, {
                                transaction: t
                            });
                        });
                    }).then(function (result) {
                        // Transaction has been committed
                    }).catch(function (err) {
                        sendEmailOnError(err, 0, 0)
                        logger.error(err);
                    })
                );
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Input On End error", error);
                logger.error(error);

            }
            return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
                    doMoreThings().then(someData => {                                                        
                        console.log('Import complete! Shutting down process now.');
                        process.exit(0);
                    })
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                    // console.log("error", e);
                    logger.error(e);
                });
```

Tried again with async...await, still the transaction doesn't rollback for truncated data.

> Un-managed transaction

```
        let t;
        try {
            t = await models.sequelize.transaction();

            //truncate table
            await infx.destroy({
                where: {},
                truncate: true,
                transaction: t
            });

            //insert new bulk collection
            await infx.bulkCreate(dataCollection, {
                transaction: t
            });

            // commit
            await t.commit();
        } catch (error) {
            // console.log("Input On End error", error);
            if (error) await t.rollback();
            sendEmailOnError(error, 0, 0);
            // logger.error(error);

        }
```

> Managed Transaction

```
try {
                result = await models.sequelize.transaction(
                    async (t) => {
                        //truncate table
                        await infx.destroy({
                            where: {},
                            truncate: true,
                            transaction: t
                        });

                        //insert new bulk collection
                        return await infx.bulkCreate(dataCollection, {
                            transaction: t
                        });
                    });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Input On End error", error);
                sendEmailOnError(error, 0, 0);
                // logger.error(error);
            }
```

> Sequelize log (everything is well executed within transaction)

```
Executing (8f53bd47-e324-48b7-8c7d-ea93dcbdae5c): START TRANSACTION;
Executing (8f53bd47-e324-48b7-8c7d-ea93dcbdae5c): TRUNCATE `infxes`
Executing (8f53bd47-e324-48b7-8c7d-ea93dcbdae5c): INSERT INTO `infxes` (...);
Executing (8f53bd47-e324-48b7-8c7d-ea93dcbdae5c): ROLLBACK;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this had to do with:

> Although TRUNCATE TABLE is similar to DELETE, it is classified as a DDL statement rather than a DML statement.
>
> - Truncate operations cause an implicit commit, and so cannot be rolled back.

**References:**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html

For my scenario, I could choose to go with delete instead of truncate:

```
           result = await models.sequelize.transaction(
                async (t) => {
                    //truncate table
                    await infx.destroy({
                        where: {},
                        transaction: t
                    });                     

                    //insert new bulk collection
                    return await infx.bulkCreate(dataCollection, {
                        transaction: t
                    });
                });
        } catch (error) {
            logger.error(error);
        }
```